# Apache lang3 works but Apache lang does not. Why?

Tags: java, maven, apache-stringutils, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

I have implemented the spring boot project with starter parent pom version 2.0.3.
When I try to use

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
```

it throws error 
import cannot be resolved. 
Even though my m2 folder (C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons) have lang package (commons-lang folder)installed.
I also have commons-lang3 folder. If I change import to

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
```

It works fine.

I have same version of starter pom in other spring boot project and there I am able to use commons.lang.
Not able to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see [the spring boot starter parent](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.3.RELEASE) depends only on commons-lang3 and not on commons-lang (which is reasonable because commons-lang3 is a newer replacement for commons-lang).

It doesn't matter that your .m2 directory contains commons-lang (probably due to some other project depending on it): as long as *your project* hasn't declared a (direct or indirect) dependency on commons-lang, none of its classes will be on your classpath.

Comment: My bad. Should have mentioned. I have same version of starter pom in other spring boot project and there I am able to use commons.lang.   Have updated the question with this info.

Comment: @VDevD: do you have any other dependencies in the other project? It's possible that one of your other dependencies pulls in commons-lang as a transient dependency. Also: why do you *need* commons-lang when you already have commons-lang3?

Comment: I checked other projects. I do have other dependencies, but none of those are giving apache.lang.

Comment: Have you checked `mvn dependency:tree` on the other project as suggested by the other answer?

Answer (score 1):

Call `mvn dependency:tree` on your "other" project. Here you can see through which path you drew commons-lang. Joachim Sauer is probably right and it is a transitive dependency that you started to use like a direct one.

Best fix would be to start to use commons-lang3 for your project (again, Joachim Sauer is right here), second best fix would be to declare commons-lang as a direct dependency in your `pom.xml`.